# Navigation on my own feed grid carousel with bootstrap jquery html

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, carousel

I made a feed grid carousel that show a sequence of clickable photos inline.
Spent a lot of time searching for a plugin like enjoy instagram plugin for wordpress, but it only works... in wordpress!

So I started to try on my own.

I achieved almost all that I want, but I still want to improve the navigation.

The problems: 
I did a div inside other, so when you mouse over in the navigation arrows(occupy 44% of left and 44% of right #changed to 14% to better visualization in fiddle), it animate inside div left/right - right/left - that's ok.
But the div occup 44% of left and right, so the photos below this arrows div are not clickable.
So i made a navigation like common carousels, having arrows on left and right and occupying less than 44%. It works ok, but I want to HIDE these div arrows and MAINTAIN the navigation.
It's possible?

Example to achieve:
[Site DoBem](http://dobem.com/) Please look their Instagram feed grid -> section "aí é vida" shows exactly what I want.

Piece of my code:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/felipelima/w8h72uvv/)

In that case I can maintain the 44 percentage and the navigation will be more accurate like the desired effect of example site.

HTML

```
<div id="containerCases">

  <div id="main">

    <div id="maincontainerCases">

      <div id="mainlist" class="contentCases">
        <div id="mainrow">
          <div class='contentCases'>
            <div class='frameCases'>
              <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="item overlay" id="image-1">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/281x200" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='contentCases'>
            <div class='frameCases'>
              <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="item overlay" id="image-2">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/281x200" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='contentCases'>
            <div class='frameCases'>
              <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="item overlay" id="image-3">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/360x200" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='contentCases'>
            <div class='frameCases'>
              <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="item overlay" id="image-4">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/281x200g" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='contentCases'>
            <div class='frameCases'>
              <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
                <div class="item overlay" id="image-5">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/281x200" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="feedleft"><!--i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i--></div>
      <div class="feedright"><!--i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i--></div>

    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#containerCases {
    width: 100%;
    /*background: lightgrey;*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
#maincontainerCases {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainlist {
    display: table;
    /*background: lightblue;*/
    white-space: nowrap;
/*  position: fixed; */
/*  overflow: hidden; */
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;

}
#mainrow {
    display: table-row;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.contentCases {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.frameCases {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    background: white;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.feedleft{
  background:red;
    position:absolute; 
  float:left; 
  left:0; 
  margin-top:-214px; 
  height:214px; 
  width:14%; 
  z-index:999;
}
.feedleft i {
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: #841173;
    color:rgba(132,17,115,0.3);
}
.feedright{ 
  background:lightblue;
    position:absolute; 
  float:right; 
  right:0; 
  margin-top:-214px; 
  height:214px; 
  width:14%; 
  z-index:999;
}
.feedright i {
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: #841173;
    color:rgba(132,17,115,0.3);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.feedright').mouseover(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#mainlist').animate
                ({
                    'margin-left' : (parseInt($(this).parent().css('width')) - parseInt($('#mainlist').css('width'))) + 'px'
                });
            });

            $('.feedleft').mouseover(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#mainlist').animate
                ({
                    'margin-left' : '0px'
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy: Change the background colour of your `div's` to `transparent` and add an arrow inside it.

```
.feedright{ 
  background:transparent;
  position:absolute; 
  float:right; 
  right:0; 
  margin-top:-214px; 
  height:214px; 
  width:14%; 
  z-index:999;
}

.feedleft{
   background:transparent;
   position:absolute; 
   float:left; 
   left:0; 
   margin-top:-214px; 
   height:214px; 
   width:14%; 
   z-index:999;
 }
```

and instead of i inside your div's just put two arrows.

```
<div class="feedleft"> << </div>
<div class="feedright"> >> </div>
```

I've tried it in your fiddle and it works.

Comment: When the mouse is over the feedleft and feedright classes still impossible to click in the a href below the navigation. I added a 'cursor:pointer' in fiddle so you can see 'the problem' when you mouse over the navs. The gap is maintain the navigation and could click in the underneath href

Comment: I see, the problem is I don't see any link in your fiddle. E.g. that a tag data toggle is not ding anything even if it is outside of the left and right divs. However there are a couple of things which might be causing this. First e.preventDefault(); inside the events, second putting a div inside a tag. Let me know if you made any change to the fiddle